# Automatically launch an MSIX-packaged desktop app from the web when it is already installed

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, clickonce, msix, windows-application-packaging

I have a Windows Forms app that is deployed through ClickOnce over a web page.
What I like about this setup is that users can install the app on their first visit, and then on the second, the app is started automatically (since it's already installed). And most importantly, this also supports automatic updates.

Now I want to move away from ClickOnce so I'm trying the MSIX approach (using a Windows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio).

Like ClickOnce, MSIX can be delivered through a web page, but I'm struggling to get the app to launch automatically on the second visit, like in the above scenario. I'm getting the popup that says the app is already installed, with the button to launch it, but I'd like it to launch automatically (just like ClickOnce).

Is it doable?

Comment: It should be an attribute of the `<OnLaunch>` element (child of `<UpdateSettings>`, which you should already have), `ShowPrompt` (IIRC). You could also use the `<AutomaticBackgroundTask>` element to signify that the installer should check every 8 hours whether updates are available -- I'm not sure whether `ShowPrompt`(?) is considered when starting from a shortcut, while it should be when starting from the Menu entry or a Tile

Comment: @Jimi You seem to be right about these attributes having [no effect from a shortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appinstallerschema/element-onlaunch#remarks), which is the use case I'm after.

Comment: Yep. Shell integration is a bit tricky. You could, for now, set it up with `AutomaticBackgroundTask` and specify a different interval than the default 8 hours, if that serves you better. I don't remember what was the actual obstacle that prevents the shortcut from working, I'll have to ask the devs